# f(x::Array{Real}) does not except f(x::Array{Float64}) in Julia

Tags: julia

consider the following example in julia

```
function f(x::Array{Real,1}, y::Real)
    return [x..., y]
end

arr = [1,2,3]
f(arr, 4.0)
```

when I run this code, I get the following error

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching f(::Array{Int64,1}, 
::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
f(::Array{Real,1}, ::Real) at ...
```

is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should write:

```
function f(x::Array{<:Real,1}, y::Real)
    return [x..., y]
end
```

This behavior is explained in this section https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#Parametric-Types-1 of the Julia manual.

The problem is that `Array{Float64,1}` is not a subtype of `Array{Real,1}` but is a subtype of `Array{<:Real,1}`.

You can check it by running the following code:

```
julia> Array{Float64,1} <: Array{Real,1}
false

julia> Array{Float64,1} <: Array{<:Real,1}
true
```

Mentally you can to read `Array{<:Real,1}` as any vector whose element type specification is a subtype of `Real`, while `Array{Real,1}` means a vector whose element type specification is exactly `Real`. Note that you can construct the latter vector, and it is sometimes useful:

```
julia> Real[1, 1.0]
2-element Array{Real,1}:
 1
 1.0
```

(note that `1` and `1.0` were left as-is, i.e. as int and float), whereas:

```
julia> [1, 1.0]
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 1.0
```

did the conversion of both elements to float.

Additionally the reason why Julia treats `Array{Real, 1}` and `Array{Float64, 1}` as subtypes of each other is that both arrays have different storage format. `Array{Float64, 1}` simply stores floats (as `Float64` is a concrete type) whereas `Array{Real, 1}` will store pointers to arbitrary reals.

Comment: Worth noting also that `Array{<:Real,2}` is just a shorthand for `Array{T,2} where T <: Real`.

Comment: If one really wants to keep `arr` as a `Vector{Real}`, then `f` needs to look something like this: `f(x::Array{Real,1}, y::Real) = push!(x, y)`, since, as @BogumilKaminski notes, `[x..., y]` promotes everything to the same concrete type.

Comment: Also in general one would better use `::AbstractArray{<:Real}`, unless there's a specific reason to accept only `Array` objects.